# Python fill matrix with specific values

Tags: python, matrix

I have 2D matrix and I want to fill it with 0 and 1. And I have a list include some value.

For example:

```
values = [1, 3, 5, 8]
```

and I want to create this matrix

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 0],
          [1, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1]]
```

I made this with two nested for loop witf if statement. Values is random integers from 0 to 100. And my matrix will be 10*10. Is there any way to create this more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list compreehension:

```
[[1 if i*10+j in values else 0 for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
```

In this case, I suggest you to create `values` as a set.

```
values = set([1, 3, 5, 8])
```

Answer (score 8):

If you can use NumPy, use fancy indexing into a flattened view of the array and reshape:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.zeros(9)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

In [4]: values = [1,3,5,8]

In [5]: a[values] = 1

In [6]: a
Out[6]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.])

In [7]: a.reshape((3,3))
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

If you want an integer array, declare `a` as `a = np.zeros(9, dtype=int)`.

Comment: And to make it more dynamic, `a = np.zeros(values.max())`

Comment: @Jérôme this would only work if `values` is a NumPy array and the desired array has a 1 in its bottom right corner (such that `values.max()` is 9 in this example) -- otherwise `a` would not be created with enough elements to reshape correctly.

Comment: Right. Dimensions are known from the start, anyway, so my comment is pointless.

Comment: I would prefer not to use numpy. Because I want  to use Python list in my code, not Numpy array. But your answer is good to know and I noted this answer for my future work. Thank you so much.